# How to quickly find/switch to the Debug Current Instruction Pointer in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

Often, when I have the Debug Current Instruction Pointer pointing at a certain line and I have to switch to another class tab, I loose the pointer location and can't remember where I last seen it. As a result, I have to spend time scrolling files and looking for it manually.

Is there a way to quickly locate the pointer or switch to it quickly?

**P.S.** I am using Eclipse.

Comment: I am not sure what you are expecting. I use navigation buttons with lady and right arrow images. Anther is using the call stack

Comment: @SravanKumarLakkimsetti I am not expecting anything, I am just asking if there is a way to find it quickly if I loose it from view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse there´s the Debug Perspective and you have a tab named Debug.
There you can see in the list of all threads and the call stack where the Pointer Location is.

Simply click on the Point in the Thread-List and you will see where the Pointer stands.

Comment: Do you know if there is a command for that, so I could create a key binding for this? I often click onto something else while debugging or go back in stacktrace and then need to use my mouse again to click to the most recent instruction. I would love to have a shortcut for this.
But maybe it is not possible because of multiple running threads and there is more than one current instruction.